# question on using pageblocksection

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, selectoption, pageblocksection

A part of VF page is below:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="EVALUATION">
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="skillreview">
        <apex:column headerValue="Parameters">  
            <apex:outputLabel value="ABC" />   
            <apex:outputLabel value="Hello" /> 
            <apex:outputLabel value="Test" /> 
            <apex:outputLabel value="XYZ" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Rating">                        
            <apex:selectList value="{!rating}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}" >
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            </apex:selectList>     
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And it is rendered as:

[image]

The value in output text is just the field api name of the object Interview__c. I have 4 field value which I would like to display in each row and have a drop down selection for each on of them visible on the page. I am trying to get the data from user for each field and update it in the database using extension class. But struck here.also, I would like the label text to appear under the parameter column. I would like it to appear like:

[image]

Comment: Share your apex code as well. I think you are getting single records here.

Comment: Well, the value in   <apex:pageblockTable value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="skillreview"> are dummy. I am not using it inside the code.

Comment: Then how can you expect four rows? They are required fields for a pageblocktable

Comment: Sorry I do not have fields to display there. I just want to display a text in each row and corresponding drop down option. Once the user selects the drop and press save , I should get the value of selected drop down and update the corresponding field using my extension.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @highfive I have made some changes in the code . I hope it explains what I want to achieve.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have made some changes in the code and screenshot . I hope it explains what I want to achieve

Comment: Since your data is not coming from controller and is static, you have 2 options. 1> Create the static data in Controller in a wrapper class and use that to iterate using pageBlockTable. 2> Instead of using pageBlockTable, use HTML table with static values.

Comment: How can I include drop down for each row if I use HTML table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is inside your interviewSkillReviews in your controller class. But in order to achieve your result, you will need something like this. In your apex controller:

```
List<skillHelper> interviewSkillReviews = new List<skillHelper>();
interviewSkillReviews.add(new skillHelper('ABC'));
interviewSkillReviews.add(new skillHelper('Hello'));
interviewSkillReviews.add(new skillHelper('Test'));
interviewSkillReviews.add(new skillHelper('XYZ'));

class skillHelper {
    public String review;
    public skillHelper (String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }
}
```

Then in your VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="EVALUATION">

    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="skillreview">
        <apex:column headerValue="Parameters">  
            <apex:outputLabel value="{skillreview.review}" />   
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column headerValue="Rating">                        
            <apex:selectList value="{!rating}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}" >
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
             </apex:selectList>     
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Apparently you need to adjust the code according to your requirement. But this should give you the idea on how to generate a table via pageBlockTable

Comment: Hello, Not sure why I get a null pointer exception at - interviewSkillReviews.add(new skillHelper('ABC'));

Comment: @SfdcBat edited my apex code which previously doesn't even compile. I am not getting the exception you mentioned as I executed in anonymous block. Would you please try again with the updated version?

Comment: I think you missed ! in <apex:outputLabel value="{!skillreview.review}" />, but I get an error - Error: Unknown property 'skillHelper.review'. Not sure why

Comment: @SfdcBat true. I missed that !. For the error you have got, simply change review into a property by adding {get; set;} after the review definition and it will work for you

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I can see the drop down now. I have a question though- I am trying to get the value of each drop down and update it 4 different fields - ABC,Test,Hello,XYZ. I was thinking to use the value of <apex:selectList value="{!rating}" in m controller to update each fields. But I have only one value for all the fields now, how can I get 4 values in 4 different variables so that I can update the fields.

Comment: @SfdcBat You should make it as a field in skillHelper class and apply it the same way as the review field into the page

Comment: this slect option - <apex:selectList value="{!rating}" will be same for all four fields right? How can I assign 4 values to the selectList value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="EVALUATION">
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="skillreview">
    <apex:column headerValue="Parameters">                                
      <apex:outputText label="Communication: Presentation of ideas, clarity of thought and expression" value="{!Interview__c.Communication__c}"/>
      <apex:outputText value="{!Interview__c.Attitude__c}"/>
    </apex:column>

   <apex:column headerValue="Rating">              
        <apex:repeat value='{!allfields}' var='field'>
            <apex:outputText label={!field.fieldname} value={!field.fieldname}/>
            <apex:selectList value="{!field.selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}"  >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!field.selectListOfValues}"/>               
             </apex:selectList>     
         </apex:repeat>
   </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>



   public fieldandparamater
{
    Interview__c interview{get;set;}
    List<wrapper> allfields{get;set;}
    fieldandparamater(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        interview = (Interview__c)controller.getRecord();
        interview = [Select fields from Interview__c]
        allfields = new  List<wrapper>();
        String[] fieldnames = new String[]{'Field1__c','Field2__c','Field3__c',Field4__c'}; 
        for(String s: fieldnames)
        {
            allfields.add(s);
        }
    }
    public pagereference save()
    {
        Sobject inter_sobj = interview;
        for(wrapper field:allfields)
        {
            inter_sobj.put(field.fieldname,field.selectedValue)
        }
        update inter_sobj;
    }
    class wrapper
    {
        public String fieldname{get;set;}
        public String selectedValue{get;set;}
        public List<SelectOption> selectListOfValues{get;set;}
        wrapper(String fieldname)
        {
            this.fieldname = fieldname;
            this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
            selectListOfValues = picklistvalues();
        }
        public List<SelectOption> picklistvalues() {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('2','2'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('3','3'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('4','4'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('5','5'));
            return options;
        }
    }
}
```